# Mishra's Factory - Rarity and Peasant/Pauper Legality

Tags: magic-the-gathering

So, I'm getting my feet wet with [Peasant Magic](https://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/feature/peasant-magic-2002-06-12), and wanted to know what exactly [Mishra's Factory](https://scryfall.com/card/atq/80a/mishras-factory?utm_source=mci) counts as in terms of rarity.

For those who don't know, Peasant is an inofficial constructed format allowing cards from all expansions - the only limitations are that you aren't allowed to use rares, and your deck may only contain a maximum of 5 uncommons. *If it was ever printed as uncommon or common*, you can bring it along.

Now, there's this card called Mishra's Factory that I'm really fond of, and that I'd like to include in my deck. Mishra's Factory is listed as uncommon, and as such can be used. So far, so good.

But:

The rarity of one of its alternative-art prints is listed not as **(U1)**, but as **(C1)** instead - which is weird because they're from the same set, and any later reprint too is listed as uncommon.

[image: The print in-question] **VS** [image: A newest print]

Now, here's my question: Is this particular old print in fact common? And as a consequence, does that mean I may freely run a full playset of Factories in Pearsant (or Pauper, even) without using up my uncommon slots on them?

If anyone could clear this up a bit, they'd be more than welcome.

Comment: humm... Gatherer lists all prints as uncommon, except for the three alternate prints as rare.

Comment: As a pre-emptive rebuttal to anyone saying "magiccards.info isn't an official source of information on cards", WOTC's own [Antiquities checklist](https://www.wizards.com/magic/generic/cardlists/Antiquities_Checklist.txt) also lists Mishra's factory at U1/C1/U1/U1. (I'm playing the devil's advocate here, as I think Gatherer is the one and only source that counts)

Comment: @Kevin, See diego's answer. A U1 is a rare, and a C1 is an uncommon.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

C1 means it is an Uncommon even though it was printed on the Common sheet.

Back when Antiquities was printed they only had 2 printing sheets, an Uncommon sheet and a Common sheet, then on each sheet there was a variable number of each card printed to create its rarity. This designation of rarity is written like U1 or C4, denoting one copy on the Uncommon sheet and 4 copies on the Common sheet respectively. U1 cards are considered Rares, U3 and C1 cards have the same rarity and are considered Uncommons, C4 cards are Commons, U2 and C2 cards are a little weird and seem to get classified as Uncommons even though they are actually more rare/common respectively. ([Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiquities_%28Magic:_The_Gathering%29#Rarity_breakdown))

When in doubt you can always check [Gatherer](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=218340). As you can see it considers 3 of the arts to be Rare (since they were printed at U1) and one of them to be Uncommon (because it was printed at C1)

Comment: Which begs the question.. It is allowed as an Uncommon? Yes, yes it is. Right from the article, Library of Alexandria is allowed even though it has Uncommon and Rare prints. It has since gained a Mythic Rare print, but again, that doesn't matter. It doesn't appear that you need to have the Uncommon print, but it's not clear.  (It says that "four copies of Library of Alexandria" are allowed, not "four copies of Library of Alexandria from Arabian Nights".)

Comment: @ikegami you mean prompts the question =) begs the question would mean the answer assumes it is allowed as an uncommon as an accepted fact for the answer, and then proceeds to prove that it is allowed as an uncommon (which would be rather silly, of course).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using http://magiccards.info/ for rarity, as gatherer has some of the cards mislabeled (or labeled as multiple rarities). Other than that, it's probably wise to use the latest printed version of the card (which in this case is uncommon).

But it entirely depends on what your playgroup agrees upon, since the format is not officially supported by WOTC, and events are most likely not sanctoined as such.

Comment: He did use magiccards.info, and why would his playgroup get to decide what's in the format?

Comment: The 'format' is not officialy supported. So unless it's a sanctioned event he's playing in (which I highly doubt, since the format is not officially supported) it's best to just discuss it within your playgroup.

Comment: Not official doesn't mean it doesn't exist. Of course you can ignore the format, but that doesn't answer questions about the format.

Comment: Never said you should ignore the format. Just saying that there aren't really 'official' rules, therefor you should be consulting your playgroup to make sure you're all on the same page.